# Maven Test command? what is the meaning for the command?

Tags: maven

E:\core\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\mvn -o clean test -Dtest=com.org.mkg.jaxb.CodeMergeTest -DskipTests=false

I am not sure what this command will do. Please someone explain.

Comment: Please use Maven 3... Maven 3.6.3 and not Maven 2 anymore it's long End of Life ...

Comment: my application is 10years old. So we are using Maven 2.2 only. Can you please explain what this command will do. after i run the command.

Comment: The command will run the given Test class only and not all tests... The `-DskipTests=false` does not makes sense...I strongly recommend to upgrade the tools as well as the app...